# Show missing data and list with existing data

Tags: sql, union

I have 2 tables
a table of PARENT ACCOUNTS (holds PARENT ID and CHILD ID)
a table of CHILD ACCOUNTS (Holds CHILD ID and ATTRIBUTE)

1 PARENT can have many CHILDREN

Each Child has one or more attributes, and each child must have the same as the other in the parent group

so if Parent 1 has Child1, Child2, Child3

Child1, Child2, Child3 MUST have the same attribute - say they are BLUE

If Child3 is missing this attribute (doesn't exist) then I need to show All the Child accounts and highlight which one is the missing one.

```
select Child, Parent,Attribute
from 
  [dbo].[AttributeTable] as AttReq
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
  [dbo].[ChildDetails] ChildDetails

 ON AttReq.Child = ChildDetails.Child
 where Parent = 'Parent1'
```

| CHILD ACOUNT | PARENT ACCOUNT | ATTRIBUTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Child1 | Parent1 | Attribute 1 |
| Child1 | Parent1 | Attribute 2 |
| Child1 | Parent1 | Attribute 3 |
| Child2 | Parent1 | Attribute 1 |
| **Child2** | **Parent1** | **Attribute 4** |
| Child2 | Parent1 | Attribute 2 |
| Child2 | Parent1 | Attribute 3 |
| Child3 | Parent1 | Attribute 1 |
| Child3 | Parent1 | Attribute 2 |
| Child3 | Parent1 | Attribute 3 |

So this one, only Child 2 has attribute 4.

I want to list all the Child accounts that are missing 4 - and which one HAS 4. I don't need to show which ones they all have.

| CHILD ACOUNT | PARENT ACCOUNT | ATTRIBUTE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Child1 | Parent1 | Missing Attribute 4 |
| Child2 | Parent1 | Missing Attribute 4 |
| Child3 | Parent1 | Has Attribute 4 |

Comment: As the *`sql` tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

If you are evaluating the instances of an attribute across several attributes, you need a sub-query to evaluate at a higher level of analysis.

I would probably do this with a case statement that sums the instances of the attribute you are looking for across each child.

To take your query as the sub-query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ATTRIBUTE = 'Attribute 4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Attribute Count]
    ,Child
    ,Parent
FROM(
SELECT Child
    ,Parent
    ,Attribute
FROM [dbo].[AttributeTable] as AttReq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ChildDetails] ChildDetails
        ON AttReq.Child = ChildDetails.Child
WHERE Parent = 'Parent1'
) Subquery
GROUP BY Child
    ,Parent
```

A child with [Attribute Count] more than 0 have the attribute. Those with 0 do not have the attribute.

Comment: thanks for the reply,

I wont know the Attribute until the first query is done as they can be added as we go - for example Hair Colour = Blue Red or Green

then someone turns up with Pink hair.

I dont want to have to hard code and add pink

Comment: Right, but your are evaluating a specific attribute. In your example, which attribute would your new column evaluate before the person with pink hair appears? Would it look for green? red? or blue?

Comment: (Meant to delete)

Comment: Yes I am looking at hair as an overall but I don't know if what colour it is until I look at the table        so 1 has red and blue hair, they must all have red and blue hair.  If 1 has red blue and yellow  I need to list all, and highlight which one had rhe yellow